# EF Core 7 with multiple dynamics where conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, where-clause, ef-core-7.0

Good morning everyone, first of all sorry for my bad English. I use EF Core 7 and I need to filter the data of a SQL database by setting a sequence of conditions whose number I don't know a priori.
These conditions apply to a single column.

If I have a single condition I use:

```
trova = (from tr in db.T_ClientiCOLs 
         where tr.Azienda.Contains(t) select tr).ToList();
```

but if I want to filter with different conditions, how can I do it?

I tried

```
string[] x = t.Split(' ');
string pSql = "";

foreach (string s in x)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    { 
        continue; 
    }
    else
    {
        if (pSql.Length > 0) 
        { 
            pSql += " AND "; 
        }

        pSql = pSql + " [Azienda] like N'%" + s + "%' ";
    }
}

FormattableString sql = $"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[T_Clienti] WHERE {pSql}";
trova = db.T_Clientis.FromSql(sql).ToList();
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Use methods instead of query form and use different `.Where(...)` calls. Eg `if(x) { query=query.Where(...);`. You can append multiple `Where` clauses and effectively get an `AND` filter

Comment: *ON THE OTHER HAND* `LIKE '%x%'` is very slow because it can't use any indexes. If you want to search for specific words it's a LOT faster to use your database's full-text-search indexing features.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server and PostgreSQL for example have full-text-search indexes and functions that can be used in EF Core using provider-specific functions, like [EF.Functions.FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-7.0) for SQL Server

Comment: I use SQL Server
As you may have understood, I should search for parts of text in the company name: for example the customer could search for "com er" or "com er pi tar nel", so I don't know how many where I will have to use.
Can I add it in a dynamic way? And how?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to modify the code:

```cs
string[] x = t.Split(' ');
var query = db.T_Clientis.AsQueryable();
foreach (string s in x)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) { continue; }
    else
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Azienda.Contains(s));
    }
}
trova = query.ToList();
```